# HDP 2.6.5 Sandbox not accessible from local

Tags: hortonworks-sandbox

After installing HDP 2.6.5 on Oracle Virtualbox 5.2.14 with ext, VM is frozen on this screen.. its not accessible by keyboard/mouse. Kindly guide how to make it readable from keyboard/mouse.

[image: VM_screenshot]

Is there some keyboard/mouse integration I am missing? Attempted some options from similar posts before posting the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Please press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. It prompts sandbox-hdp login. Login here using **username:password** ie,  **root:hadoop** credentials. After successful login, it would prompt you to change the root user password. Below tutorial from hortonworks explains a complete setup process https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/learning-the-ropes-of-the-hortonworks-sandbox/#terminal-access.

Comment: It does not explain why the welcome page is not available through the browser.